# Autocomplete in XSLT Development in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, autocomplete

Is there a setting or plugin or something else that allows Eclipse to autocomplete XPaths when developing XSLTs in Eclipse?

In Stylus Studio, if you set the source XML in an XSLT transformation scenario, if you are typing a tag out (say like in an test or select statement), Stylus Studio will start autocompleting the tag you are typing and will show you tags underneath it if you put the / mark at the end of it. I'm trying to see if this functionality is in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know Stylus Studio but oXygen has a plugin for Eclipse so you might want to check if Stylus Studio has something similar to integrate in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually trying to steer away from Stylus if I could and just use Eclipse. I like oXygen much better but my workplace only has Stylus at the moment.